# how to use omxcodec in android for all version

Tags: android

I want to decode and display h264 frame over my screen. Now all I wanted to do is to use omx codec to decode my frames as it decodes in hardware which helps achieve fps for high resolutions. Till now all I come to know is there are different way to access hardware decoder. I come across some names like stagefright, omxcodec, openmax. All are these are different things. I want to decode frame by frame. and upto my knowledge android libraries accept only file path or url of media. But here my requirement is different. I need to decode frame by frame. So can someone tell me where can I start digging? I come to know that in latest version of android, they have published api to decode. But I want to support all version of android. So any suggestion or guidance will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, indeed at the top level libstagefright library has a "stream" interface. 
That is, you create audio- or video-source, configure codecs, and then start the process of encoding or decoding.

However, using an interface OMXCodec you can obtain access to the individual frames.
Unfortunately, I do not know any source of official OMXCodec documentations.

The only source - these are examples of the code in the Android repository.

If you want to know more about how to use OMXCodec, you can view the AwesomePlayer.cpp file
(http://gitorious.org/rowboat/frameworks-base/blobs/rowboat-ics/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp)

Using the library libstagefright is clear from the StagefrightRecorder.cpp (in the same repository)

Also useful information about the OMXCodec architecture is
[here](http://vec.io/posts/use-android-hardware-decoder-with-omxcodec-in-ndk)

P.S. Remember that the OMXCodec API not stable and may vary from version to version...

Comment: Andrew thanks for your response. please go through my question list. I have got the reference from the same you mentioned. and what I can achieve can be concluded from my questions with stagefright key word. thanks for the response.